# Creating WWF workflow dynamically using XAML + X:name is not working

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

I am creating a custom workflow activities, these activities have a base class as shown below

```
public class BaseClass : SequenceActivity
{ }

public class Activity1 : BaseClass
{ }

public class Activity2 : BaseClass
{ }
```

Then I write the xoml of the workflow as shown below

```
<GS1:Activity1 x:Name="Activity2"></GS1:Activity1>
<GS1:Activity2 x:Name="Activity3"></GS1:Activity2>
```

everything works fine until i want to start the workflow

```
workflowRuntime.CreateWorkflow(Type.GetType("WorkflowType Full Name"), null, Guid.NewGuid());
```

I get the below error

```
error 1538: Activity 'BaseClass' validation failed: There is already an activity named 'BaseClass'. Activity names must be unique.
```

Note that the above was working correctly on WF3.5, this error appeared when I upgraded to WF4.0.

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are combining WF3 and WF4 classes here. It is a bit confusing because they are similar and both have an Activity class but there is no relation. The WorkflowRuntime is a WF3 type. With WF4 you can use the WorkflowApplication or the WorkflowInvoker to run a workflow.

Comment: Yeah correct, I am still using the WorkflowRuntime. I will check the WorkflowApplication and WorkflowInvoker. Thank you

Comment: Can I use the WorkflowInvoker to run a dynamic workflow, I mean pass the type to the WorkflowInvoker

Comment: You pass an instance to the WorkflowInvoker. You can be as dynamic as you want because you van use the ActivityXamlServices.Load() to load a piece of XAML at runtime if you like.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to have a backward compatibility for .Net3.5 while working in .Net4.0

Comment: The complete WF3 stack is still there in .NET 4 so the backward compatibility is taken care of. As far as WF4 and WF3 there is no compatibility, WF4 is a complere rewrite from the ground up.